# JSON encode/decode utf8 strings in Perl

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I pass a [utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) encoded string from my command line into a Perl program:

```
> ./test.pl --string='ḷet ūs try ṭhiñgs'
```

which seems to recognize the string correctly:

```
use utf8;  

GetOptions(                                                                     
    'string=s' => \$string,                                                     
) or die;                                                                    
print Dumper($string);
print Dumper(utf8::is_utf8($string));                                           
print Dumper(utf8::valid($string));
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = 'ḷet ūs try ṭhiñgs';
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR1 = 1;
```

When I store this string into a hash and call [encode_json](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#encode_json) on it, the string seems to be *again* encoded whereas [to_json](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#to_json) seems to work (if I read the output correctly):

```
my %a = ( 'nāme' => $string ); # Note the Unicode character                                                 
print Dumper(\%a);
print Dumper(encode_json(\%a));                                                 
print Dumper(to_json(\%a));
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = {
          "n\x{101}me" => 'ḷet ūs try ṭhiñgs'
        };
$VAR1 = '{"nāme":"á¸·et Å«s try á¹­hiÃ±gs"}';
$VAR1 = "{\"n\x{101}me\":\"\x{e1}\x{b8}\x{b7}et \x{c5}\x{ab}s try \x{e1}\x{b9}\x{ad}hi\x{c3}\x{b1}gs\"}";
```

Turning this back into the original hash, however, doesn't seem to work with either methods and in both cases hash and string and broken:

```
print Dumper(decode_json(encode_json(\%a)));                                    
print Dumper(from_json(to_json(\%a)));
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = {
           "n\x{101}me" => "\x{e1}\x{b8}\x{b7}et \x{c5}\x{ab}s try \x{e1}\x{b9}\x{ad}hi\x{c3}\x{b1}gs"
        };
$VAR1 = {
          "n\x{101}me" => "\x{e1}\x{b8}\x{b7}et \x{c5}\x{ab}s try \x{e1}\x{b9}\x{ad}hi\x{c3}\x{b1}gs"
        };
```

A hash lookup `$a{'nāme'}` now fails.

**Question:** How do I handle utf8 encoding and strings and JSON encode/decode correctly in Perl?

Comment: It's obvious from your very first `print Dumper(utf8::is_utf8($string));` returning `''` that the string is not recognised as UTF-8.

Comment: ...but the `utf8::valid($string)` returns true.

Comment: @Jens That doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @MattJacob: uhm... ok? :-)

Comment: @Jens In this case, "valid" means "consistent". It's marked "[INTERNAL](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8)" for a reason. Just... don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decode your input:

```
use Encode;

my $string;
GetOptions('string=s' => \$string) or die;
$string = decode('UTF-8', $string);
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;

use Encode;
use Getopt::Long;
use JSON;

my $string;
GetOptions('string=s' => \$string) or die;
$string = decode('UTF-8', $string);

my %hash = ('nāme' => $string);
my $json = encode_json(\%hash);
my $href = decode_json($json);

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');
say $href->{nāme};
```

Example:

```
$ perl test.pl --string='ḷet ūs try ṭhiñgs'
ḷet ūs try ṭhiñgs
```

Make sure your source file is actually encoded as UTF-8!

Comment: That doesn't address the hash after the `from_json`, does it?

Comment: @Jens Don't use `to_json`/`from_json`. Use `encode_json`/`decode_json` instead to maintain UTF-8.

Comment: So how would I handle the hash lookup at the end of my question correctly then?

Comment: @Jens If you use `encode_json` on a hash reference, you'll get a string that represents a JSON object. If you use `decode_json` on a string containing a JSON object, you'll get a hash reference. So, `$href = decode_json('{...}'); say $href->{'nāme'};`

Comment: Thanks! I see that you also added [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).

Comment: @Jens Yes, you need to encode your output, and that will do it automatically for `STDOUT`.

Comment: The line `binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');` solved my problem to output JSON in UTF-8 :)