# JSON encoding in Perl output

Tags: json, perl, encoding

**Context:**
I have to migrate a Perl script, into Python. The problem resides in that the configuration files that this Perl script uses, is actually valid Perl code. My Python version of it, uses .yaml files as config.

<s>Therefore, I basically had to write a converter between Perl and yaml. Given that, from what I found, Perl does not play well with Yaml, but there are libs that allow dumping Perl hashes into JSON, and that Python works with JSON -almost- natively, I used this format as an intermediate: Perl -> JSON -> Yaml. The first conversion is done in Perl code, and the second one, in Python code (which also does some mangling on the data).</s>

Using the library mentioned by @simbabque, I can output YAML natively, which afterwards I must modify and play with. As I know next to nothing of Perl, I prefer to do so in Python.

**Problem:**
The source config files look something like this:

```
$sites = {
    "0100101001" => {
        mail => 1,
        from => 'mail@mail.com',
        to => 'mail@mail.com',
        subject => 'á é í ó ú',
        msg => 'á é í ó ú',
        ftp => 0,
        sftp => 0,
    },
    "22222222" => {
[...]
```

And many more of those.

My "parsing" code is the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# use JSON;
use YAML;
use utf8;
use Encode;
use Getopt::Long;

my $conf;
GetOptions('conf=s' => \$conf) or die;
our (
    $sites
);
do $conf;

# my $json = encode_json($sites);
my $yaml = Dump($sites);

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');
# print($json);
print($yaml);
```

Nothing out of the ordinary. I simply need the <s>JSON</s> YAML version of the Perl data. In fact, it mostly works. My problem is with the encoding.

The output of the above code is this:

```
  [...snip...]
  mail: 1
  msg: Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº
  sftp: 0
  subject: Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº
  [...snip...]
```

The encoding goes to hell and back. As far as I read, UTF-8 is the default, and just in case, I force it with binmode, but to no avail.

What am I missing here? Any workaround?

Note: I thought I may have been my shell, but `locale` outputs this:

```
❯ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Which seems ok.

Note 2: I know next to nothing of Perl, and is not my intent to be an expert on it, so any enhancements/tips are greatly appreciated too.

Note 3: I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494740/1802024), and my code is loosely based on it. The main difference is that I'm not sure how to *encode* a file, instead of a simple string.

Comment: The converter for converting Perl data structures to YAML is one of the many YAML modules on CPAN. [Take your pick](https://metacpan.org/search?q=YAML). No need to reinvent the wheel or even do this by hand.

Comment: Why didn't I find that module before... Also, didn't know about metacpan. Thanks for the tip. Anyhow, my problem is that I have to manipulate the data a bit, and I'd take days to do so in Perl, considering how little I know of it. In Python I did it in a few minutes. However, I like this lib, and maybe I could save a conversion. Thanks!

Comment: And in regards to _Perl does not play well with YAML_, you do know that [one of the three core people behind YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#History_and_name) is actually [a big name in the Perl community](https://metacpan.org/author/INGY)? There are actually a few people from the Perl world involved with YAML. :) There is also a trove of stuff about Perl and YAML in [tinita's blog on blogs.perl.org](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/).

Comment: You are completely right. In fact, I think I made that statement entirely out of not knowing enough Perl and avoiding delving deeper into it. Saaaadly, the problem stands. Just changed the lib used, and the output is still messed up: `subject: Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº` :(

Comment: Don't worry about it. Your approach to convert to a known format was sound. You just lacked some research. :)

Comment: Does the Perl config file have the `use utf8` pragma? I see you have it in yoru _converter_, but it only has an effect of how Perl treats strings from the source code of the file that pragma is in. It has nothing to do with input and output.

Comment: No! It was a bare Perl file, with only variable definitions! Adding the pragma did the trick! This makeshift converter is wrapped in a Bash script, so I may do a `grep` on it before converting, and adding the pragma if not found. Or is there a way to force it upon reading the file? (also, please move this to an answer so I can accept it!)

Comment: Looks like mob beat me. That's ok though. They need the points to get to the t-shirt, and I already have two! :)

Comment: @simbabque: You have *two*? What makes you so special!

Comment: @Borodin I got them both from the 10m questions thing. One for writing a post about a special answer on SO, and one for apparently someone writing one about me, though I never found it. I also have a mug and a load of stickers.

Comment: @simbabque: Oh, I think you've talked about it before. Well done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sites config file is UTF-8 encoded. Here are three workarounds:

1. Put `use utf8` pragma inside the site configuration file. The `use utf8` pragma in the main script is not sufficient to treat files included with `do`/`require` as UTF-8 encoded.
2. If that is not feasible, decode the input before you pass it to the JSON encoder. Something like

   ```
   open CFG, "<:encoding(utf-8)", $conf;
   do { local $/; eval <CFG> };
   close CFG;
   ```

instead of

```
do $conf
```

3. Use `JSON::to_json` instead of `JSON::encode_json`. `encode_json` expects decoded input (Unicode code points) and the output is UTF-8 encoded. The output of `to_json` is not encoded, or rather, it will have the same encoding as the input, which is what you want.

There is no need to encode the final output as UTF-8. Using any of the three workarounds will already produce UTF-8 encoded output.

Comment: Option 2 gives me the creeps.

Comment: In the question's comments, @simbabque mentioned the YAML library, and I think I'll go straight to YAML. With that, the option 2 looks good (even considering the creeps). However, doesn't seem to load the file correctly, as the `sites` variable is still uninitialized (the resulting yaml is empty). Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Option 2 is exactly as creepy as `do $conf`

Comment: In hindsight, I feel like most of the stuff I'm doing here is creepy.

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm going to be embarrassed here, but why do you have both `do` and `eval`? I can't see why `{ local $/; eval <CFG>; }`wouldn't do everything you need when you're discarding the result of `do`.

Comment: For decoration? You're right -- the `do` is optional here.